# SqlServer 2000 enterprise (32bit) running on WinServer 2003 enterprise (64-bit). How to see more memory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, 64-bit

have a server running windows 2003 enterprise edition 64-bit and this server has 18GB of Ram.

I am running Sql Server 2000 enterprise edition (32-bit) on it. Sql server is only using 4GB of RAM.

I see some articles online claiming you need to configure SQLServer to use AWE to access more than 4 GB. However [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190673.aspx) article states that **AWE is not required and cannot be configured on 64-bit operating systems**.

I tried setting the Min Memory for the server, however I get the following message in the sql error log: **Warning: unable to allocate 'min server memory' of 14748MB.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be on SQL Server 2000 SP4. Though Windows 2003 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) doesn't support PAE, it does support the APIs 32-bit apps will use to make the calls. So you can enable SQL Server to use AWE memory and adjust the memory accordingly. More info can be found in [this thread](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-clustering/2452/SQL-Server-2000-AWE-on-Windows-2003-64bit).

Answer (score 0):

I quote Microsoft regarding AWE:

> This feature will be removed in the next version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible.

Why not just upgrade to SQL Server 64-bit?  You do need AWE for more than 4GB, because the limit of the address space of any 32-bit process is 4GB.  That's the laws of mathematics, not Microsoft.